# Polymer: register a behaviour at runtime

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I need to setup the behaviour of a polymer web-compontent at runtime. I tried to change the "behaviours" array by pushing the new behaviour, but it didn't work. Is there a proper way to do it?

I'm trying to create a table web-component with a pager at bottom. It should be extensible allowing the loading of data from a javascript array, a restful service or a custom source. Thus, I decided to create a behaviour for each one of these source and change it when the source changes. Is it a correct way to design it?

Here as example [the source code](https://github.com/donpir/polywc-data-table/blob/943bf5144edc77efd36d5ac37f3d2e09c23894dc/data-table-pager/data-table-pager-array-behaviour.html) of the behaviour to load data from an array. It has the following function:

```
itemsLoad: function(page, itemsPerPage, callback) {...
```

which is called from the web-component to load data of a specific page. My idea is that each behaviour based on the type of data source (e.g. CSV, JSON, etc.) will implement this method in a different way. Then, the behaviour will be registered at run-time, because is at run-time that the developers knows which is the source to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to change behaviours at run-time, because they are mixed into the element prototype.

What you can do is create a separate element for each of your cases (csv, json, etc) and create nodes dynamically as required. You could than place that element inside your grid

```
<table-component>
   <json-data-source></json-data-source>
</table-component>
```

The `<table-component>` would look for a child element which implements `itemsLoad` to get the data.

**EDIT**

To work with child nodes you would use [Polymer's DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api). For example you could listen to added child nodes and select one that implements the `itemsLoad` method.

```
Polymer({
  attached: function() {
    Polymer.dom(this).observeNodes(function(info) {
      var newNodes = info.addedNodes; 

      for(var i=0; i<newNodes.length; i++) {
        var dataSource = newNodes[i];

        if(dataSource.itemsLoad && typeof dataSource.itemsLoad === 'function') {
          this.loadItems(dataSource);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  loadItems: function(dataSource) {
    dataSource.itemsLoad().then(...);
  }
});
```

You could replace [`Polymer.dom(this).observeNodes`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#observe-nodes) with simply iteration over `Polymer.dom(this).children`. Whichever works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I look for the child element <json-data-source> and determine whether it implements itemsLoad?

Comment: With Polymer it's basically almost like ordinary DOM manipulation. And checking whether element implements a function? Check whether it exists. See updated answer